# Java Thread Complete Event

Tags: java, multithreading

I am making a Swing application, and I have a `Runnable` class that runs a thread, and the thread makes an HTTP request what is the best way to know when the thread finished?

```
private void loginMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    login.setEnabled(false);
    loading.setVisible(true);

    DoLogin log = new DoLogin(user.getText(), pass.getPassword().toString());
    Thread t = new Thread(log);
    t.start();

    loading.setVisible(false);
    login.setEnabled(true);
}
```

I would like to move the last 2 lines of that method to another method that gets fired off when the thread completes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). Do the login in the `doInBackground()` method, and put your other two lines of code in the `done()` method.

It is important to do it this way, rather than simply adding the additional actions to perform to the end of the login thread, or spawning yet another thread for them, because they update your UI and so you want to perform them on the Swing UI thread. `SwingWorker`'s `done()` method will be invoked on the Swing UI thread.

Comment: It's precisely what `SwingWorker` was created for.

Comment: Do I extend my DoLogin class? or my JFrame class?

Answer (score 0):

You pass a task - an implementation of runnable to the thread to process. The thread complete when it processes this task.

You can pass a callback listener to your task, which will notify just before task completion.

In the constructor of Do login pass an implementation of the below interface

```
interface ICompletionListener {
void onCompletion();
}
```

In the runnable implementation invoke a onCompletion on this object; and in the implementation of this interface perform the last two lines of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DoLogin` `Runnable` can implement a Listener that would execute when the process is completed.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243657/is-it-possible-to-write-your-own-objects-that-give-out-actionevents/14244393#14244393) for more details on how to create your own Listener.

Answer (score 0):

Well, wrap your `DoLogin` into new `Runnable` in such way:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
          DoLogin log = new DoLogin(user.getText(), pass.getPassword().toString());
          log.run();

          // placing here finishing stuff
          loading.setVisible(false);
          login.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
Thread t = new Thread(r);
t.start();
```