# Java Event Model similar to GWT Event Handling?

Tags: java, gwt, event-handling

I've used Event Handling in GWT which is superb, is there anything like this in Java, I've been googling about it, did not find anything concrete, does someone have any idea about it?

Comment: Be more specific.  Swing Listeners seem similar to the GWT event handling.

Comment: it is not only about the Graphical User interface, is it possible to create your own type of event, then have event handlers that are executed when an event of a particular event type is created

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243657/is-it-possible-to-write-your-own-objects-that-give-out-actionevents/14244393#14244393

Comment: thankyou, that's what i was actually looking for