# Java - Fire an event to another thread on data reception

Tags: java, multithreading, event-handling, nio

I have to write a server that manages several Datagram sockets.
I know about the selector capabily of java.nio that allows async management of different sockets
However, after having parsed the message I need to fire an event to another thread (optionally with some parameters).
Is there a way to make other threads to "register" to the one that manages the sockets and make them aware that data is ready for them?
Thanks in advance

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14244393/300257

Answer (score 2):

You can use have an ExecutorService that backs the async network call.  The Future returned at that point can act as the message passer upon completion.

```
public class SocketWork<T>{

    private final ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private final Future<T> future;

    public SocketWork(){
        future = service.submit(new SocketWorkCallable<T>());    
    }

    public T register(){
        // all threads entering register will block until 
        // the SocketWorkCallable is completed and returns.
       return future.get();
    }
}
```

An alternative is to use a CountdownLatch.

```
public class SocketWork<T>{

    private final CountdownLatch latch = new CountdownLatch(1);
    private T message;

    public void executeSocketWork(){
        //execute work and get message
        this.message = returnedMessage;
        latch.countDown();
    }

    public T register(){
        latch.await();
        return message;
    }
}
```

You could do something similar with a ReadWriteLock as well.

As you can imagine this will only work for a single task.  Per instance of `SocketWork`